# How to remove the border in recyclerview (RecyclerView.Adapter)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create message app for the first time and i am stack at this border 
created by recyclerview. So can someone know how to remove this from recyclerview

[recyclerview (RecyclerView.Adapter)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljKSi.jpg) 
UPDATE:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/chat_list"
        app:reverseLayout="true"
        android:background="@color/lightgray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

RecyclerView XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/message_single_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/message_profile_layout"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/message_profile_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/white_rounded_chat"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:paddingStart="12dp"
                android:paddingRight="12dp"
                android:paddingEnd="12dp"
                android:text="Message Text"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" /> 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: RecyclerView does not create any borders. You probably have added them in the items layout.

Comment: Share item layout xml code

Comment: Please check it

Comment: `white_rounded_chat` I guess this background contains border

Comment: did you use DividerItemDecoration without knowing it?

Comment: No I am not using it

Comment: @ZaidMirza **white_rounded_chat** its in the child, it has nothing to do with border which is coming after everything close

Comment: @DamianJäger  can you help me out ?

Comment: @VolkanSahin45 please look at xml

Comment: can u share your recylerview xml code.

Comment: Do you modify the views in your viewholder?

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH please check now

Comment: @DamianJäger No i have not

Comment: Try recylerview.addItemDecoration(null); or set background to relative layout in item layout.

Comment: Try removing these two lines: android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/message_profile_layout" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/message_profile_layout"

Comment: @DamianJäger No bro .. nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
recylerview.addItemDecoration(null);
```

Or

```
 RecyclerView.ItemDecoration decoration = new RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            super.onDraw(c, parent, state);
        //empty
        }
    };

    simpleListView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
```